# C++ template operator+ overloading in inner class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

How do I overload operator+ for inner class of a class template? I've searched for hours now and I can't find an answer. This is a minimal example that does not work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        T m_t;
        B(T t) : m_t(t) {}
    };


};

template <class T>
typename A<T>::B operator+(typename A<T>::B lhs, int n)
{
    lhs.m_t += n;
    return lhs;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

    A<float> a;
    A<float>::B b(17.2);
    auto c = b + 5;
    cout << c.m_t << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile like this, I get `error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘A<float>::B’ and ‘int’)`

I found somewhere that `operator+(A<T>::B, int)` should be declared, so if I add the following:

```
struct B;
friend B operator+(typename A<T>::B lhs, int n);
```

after `struct A {`, I get a linker error.

If I don't try to call b+5, the program compiles correctly.

How did they (STL makers) program `vector<T>::iterator operator+` with an int? I can't find it anywhere (and it's kind of hard to read stl_vector.h)!

Thank you.

Comment: there is no inheritance, what you call "child" class I would rather call "inner" / "nested" class

Comment: did you try to have the operator as a member function?

Comment: `T` in `typename A<T>::B lhs` is non-deducible, hence this overload is not viable for the call

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is that when you declare a function template like:

```
template <class T>
typename A<T>::B operator+(typename A<T>::B lhs, int n)
```

`typename A<T>::B lhs` is a **non-deduced context**. There is no way for the compiler to determine what `T` is in that context, so it doesn't try, so it cannot find your `operator+`. Consider a reduced example like:

```
template <class T> void foo(typename T::type );

struct A { using type = int; };
struct B { using type = int; };

foo(0); // what would T be? 
        // how many other possible T's are there that fit?
```

In order for template deduction to succeed with non-deduced contexts, the template type parameter must be explicitly specified. In this case, this monstrosity of a syntax compiles:

```
auto c = ::operator+<float>(b, 5);
```

But probably isn't your intended usage!

---

You will need to declare the `operator+` within `struct B`:

```
struct B
{
    T m_t;
    B(T t) : m_t(t) {}

    // member
    B operator+(int n) {
        return B(m_t + n);
    }

    // or non-member, non-template friend
    friend B operator+(B lhs, int n) {
        lhs.m_t += n;
        return lhs;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        typedef A<T> OuterType;
        T m_t;
        B(T t) : m_t(t) {}
    };


};

template <class T>
typename T::OuterType::B operator+(T lhs, int n)
{
    lhs.m_t += n;
    return lhs;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    A<float> a;
    A<float>::B b(17.2);
    auto c = b + 5;
    cout << c.m_t << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**  This would work as the T is deducable from first operand of expression `(b + 5)` and works only for the structs that contains `OuterType` struct defined that has subtype B as an inner struct. You can test if this struct is the same as T using `typename enable_if<is_same<T, typename T::OuterType::B>::value, T>::type` instead of result type: `typename T::OuterType::B`